# How to remove or hide /#file_name from the url

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

URL shows like `domain.com/#main`

I just want only `domain.com`,

there are no anchor tags with id attributes to scroll.

how to remove or hide it.

Comment: Can you give example? Probably your router is set on that way

Comment: How are you loading/getting to the page?

Comment: Your question tags are not helpful. Your issue does not seem to be related to javascript, php, html or css

Comment: @smartdroid Can certainly be modified with javascript, why wouldn't that apply?

Comment: @charlietfl - good to know. Apologies for my ignorance. It will help, If you could show a solution using javascript.

Comment: @smartdroid Open dev tools console and run `history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');`. after you lcik on link to this comment or add a hash manually in this page first

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks

Comment: My impression is, we are guessing. @Charan Chetu can you please give minimal excerpt of the code not working? Where does this url come from?

Answer (score 1):

`history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');` will remove the url hash without causing page to reload